# Oracle APEX Custom Success Message

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Hi i can not create custom success message.
I try in 2 different ways

1st I change the success message in the process from the Clients:
[image]

2nd i create a new success message process :

[image]

But I still get the typical success message:

[image]

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Did you find the anwswer?

Comment: Hi @Paulo Künzel and sorry for the delay of my response. Yes i found a solution. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can customize the success msg. Go to JavaScript -> Function and Global Variable Declaration and there you can write something like that:

```
function show_notification0(Msg){  
        apex.message.showPageSuccess(Msg); 
        $('#t_Alert_Success').attr('style','background-color: rgb(235, 52, 116);');
        $('.t-Alert-title').attr('style','color: yellow;font-weight: bold;');
        $('#t_Alert_Success div div.t-Alert-icon span').removeClass('t-Icon').addClass('fa fa-ban fa-2x fa-anim-flash fam-x fam-is-danger');
        $('#t_Alert_Success  div div.t-Alert-icon span').attr('style','color: black');
}
```

[image]

You can find all the icons that you can use in many ways in this site: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/icons

for example, if you want a flashing 2x scale bus to appear instead of a check, you can get the code from this site (fa-bus fa-2x fa-anim-flash) and replace it, in the above .addClass (fa-anim-flash fam-x fam-is-danger).

You can also change the background color (rgb in our example)  of alert msg or Alert-title color and font-weight or even your icon color.

After that you have to go to Refresh on Dialog Close that you want to change and there you can create a true Execute JavaScript Code like this:

```
show_notification0('Address Successfully Updated');
```

This is the name (show_notification0) of your Global Function that you create in your page attribute. In my second picture example, i call this function "show_notificationS".

[image]